# How to force Bindy to always return List?

Tags: java, apache-camel, bindy

I have the following route:

```
from("direct:abc")
        // read the file  
        .split(body().tokenize("\n", 3, false)).streaming().stopOnException()
        .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(Foo.class))
        .process(new FooListProcessor());
```

The problem is that if I have 4 records in file first group comes in processor as `List` but the second as a single `Foo` object. 
I have to check body with `instanceof` and create a list every time when such cases occurs.

`Foo` class:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public class Foo {
   @DataField(pos = 1)
   private String fooField;
   @DataField(pos = 2, trim = true)
   private String barField;
}
```

File content:

```
"lorem","ipsum"
"dolorem","sit"
"consectetur","adipiscing"
"eiusmod","incididunt"
```

Is there a way to force `Bindy` to always unmarshall into a `List`?

Comment: can you show the file content snippet and also your Foo Class

Comment: @pvpkiran, I've updated the question with details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No bindy returns a single instance if there is single instance. And a list of there are more.

I have logged a ticket for an improvement so you can configure this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12321

Comment: unwrapSingleInstance = false should always return an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small point. Since it is not supported as @Claus said, instead of you doing instance of check in processor code, you could as well do it in the route like this and let camel handle it for you.

```
  from("file:///tmp/camel/input")
            // read the file
            .split(body().tokenize("\n", 3, false)).streaming().stopOnException()
            .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(Foo.class))
            .choice()
            .when(body().isInstanceOf(List.class))
                .process(exchange -> { // Your logic here for list})
            .otherwise()
                .process(exchange -> {// Your logic here for individual items})
            .endChoice();
```