# Spring Boot auto-configuration not working for Apache Camel Bindy

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, bindy

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49108296/4071001), and in the official documentation itself: the [`unwrapSingleInstance`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/dataformats/bindy-dataformat.html#_dataformat_option_unwrapSingleInstance) property allows us to establish *"when unmarshalling should a single instance be unwrapped and returned instead of wrapped in a java.util.List"*.

However, the [`camel.dataformat.bindy-csv.unwrap-single-instance`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/dataformats/bindy-dataformat.html#_sb_option_camel_dataformat_bindy-csv_unwrap-single-instance) auto-configuration property of Spring Boot has no effect on the documentation example:

```
BindyCsvDataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(com.acme.model.MyModel.class);

from("file://inbox")
  .unmarshal(bindy)
  .to("direct:handleOrders");
```

The above example only works by setting the property this way, directly in the code:

```
bindy.setUnwrapSingleInstance(false);
```

I guess this is because the `new BindyCsvDataFormat` object is not managed by Spring, so how can I get Spring to create and manage it for auto-configuration to take effect in Apache Camel?

---

I tried to create a regular bean in Spring and set the reference in `unmarshal`, and auto-configuration has no effect either:

```
@Bean
public DataFormat bindyCsvDataFormat() {
    return new BindyCsvDataFormat(com.acme.model.MyModel.class);
}

from("file://inbox")
  .unmarshal("bindyCsvDataFormat")
  .to("direct:handleOrders");
```

---

I have this dependency in `pom.xml` with Apache Camel version `3.20.5`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-bindy-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the two following classes:

https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot/tree/main/components-starter/camel-bindy-starter/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/dataformat/bindy/csv/springboot

As you will see, Camel will "auto-mount" several Bindy-oriented classes, so that they will be auto-wired when Spring(Boot) is going to instantiate the bindy component.

And that case, you should of course NOT create your beans using the vanilla constructor (eg `new BindyCsvDataFormat`)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do it? I tried to create a regular bean in Spring and it has no effect (I updated the question with the details).

Comment: Do you use the `camel-bindy-starter` dependency (and not the `camel-bindy`) ?

Comment: By using it, Spring will auto load the beans specified in https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot/blob/main/components-starter/camel-bindy-starter/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports

Comment: I have the correct dependency in `pom.xml` with Apache Camel version `3.20.5`